# AppDelegate: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, appdelegate

I am making a simple call from the AppDelegate:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.myaction()
```

the action opens up an url in a Web View object (which is loaded on the didload override)

and this is the function:

```
func myaction() {
   let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.5/doit")
   let urlreq = URLRequest(url: url!)
   mywebview.loadRequest(urlreq)
}
```

and this is the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error. I'll wager it's *let urlreq...* Why because that's the only line where you are trying to unwrap something. I'll also bet that if you put a breakpoint on that line and check the contents of *url* you'll find it nil. (Of course, unless you didn't post the code that's really giving you fits.) So the question you need to really ask - if I'm correct here - is what is blocking your HTTP request.

Comment: Have you set the ATP setting in your Info.plist? If not, your URL request will be denied due to it not being https

Comment: Try to add arbitrary loads to YES in the app transport security's dictionnary

Comment: If you are using storyboard, `vc` is not the expected instance designed in Interface Builder. So the `IBOutlet` is not connected. You need the *real* reference to `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found nil is probably for `mywebView` because it will only initialise when your `viewcontroller` view load. Try with the following code

```
func myaction() {
    let mywebview = UIWebView()
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.5/doit")
    let urlreq = URLRequest(url: url!)
    mywebview.loadRequest(urlreq)
}
```

or you can initialise the mywebview outside of `myaction()`.

Answer (score 0):

try NSURL:

```
func myaction() {
   let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.5/doit")
   let urlreq = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
   mywebview.loadRequest(urlreq)
}
```